# Redirect a page using img src

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to redirect a page using only `<img src="?">` without using js. How ever the code has to be within src="" property, Is it possible?

Comment: no it is not sorry use 301

Comment: Why not wrap it with `<a>` tag?

Comment: No this is not possible, img src(source) is relate to the location/path where the image is stored. Wrap a <a href"#">..yourimage</a> around it and you'll be able to link your image.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to a page when clicking an image ?

Comment: Its more like a pixel tracking url, which could be redirected to a desired url

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You would need javascript and more than just a `src` attribute, such as `onload` or `onerror`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to **redirect** with HTML is

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
      content="delay_in_seconds;URL=redirect_to_this_url" />
```

The `<a>` tag isn't a redirection.
`<a>` and `<form>` are the only way to make the client send a new request by clicking on something.

You need at least JavaScript or a plugin (like Flash) to redirect through an image loading.